# Image mapping in html. When i hover , want to display link name?

Tags: html

I am working on image mapping . I used above code in image i got link in different parts of images , but when i hover i want to get alt name . how can i do this ? thank you in advance .

```
<map id="rade_img_map_1342182469821" name="rade_img_map_1342182469821">
    <area shape="CIRCLE" coords="121,198,15" href="http://Portfolio.com" target="_blank" alt="Portfolio" />
</map>
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Image+mapping+in+html.+When+i+hover+%2C+want+to+display+link+name%3F

Comment: Have you tried the `title` attribute of the `<area>` tag?

Comment: I have one more problem . i used title its working fine .but i want to give some test in the link . when that site opens . i want to display given text in that site . how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `title` attribute of the `<area>` tag.

E.g.

```
<area shape="CIRCLE" coords="121,198,15" href="http://Portfolio.com" 
  target="_blank" alt="Portfolio" title="Portfolio" />
```

Comment: I have one more problem . i used title its working fine .but i want to give some test in the link . when that site opens . i want to display given text in that site . how can i do this? –

Comment: @user1511098 - You want the popup-text (the `title` attribute) to be the of the title of page that the link will navigate to?! That's quite a big question (and could end up being quite a complex piece of work). It should be asked separately... not as part of a comment on this question

Comment: @user1511098 - reading your comment again... I think I might have mis-understood your question. Can you explain in a bit more details what you're after?

Comment: No, suppose if i  click on products its as to display  inside the link ,i need to display some  text <area shape="RECT" coords="150,434,238,506" href="http://Products.com" target="_blank" alt="Products" title="Products" />

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add

```
title="Porfolio"
```

Comment: I have one more problem . i used title its working fine .but i want to give some test in the link . when that site opens . i want to display given text in that site . how can i do this? –

Comment: you mean force a particular title to show on the page load? It isn't clear what you mean display given text how? Is javascripting a possibility?